# Show dialog on Google Maps V3 Java Script API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In google maps Api for javaScript V3 , it's possible show dialog same as location dialog
Example:
[image]

When click some marker:

```
 marker.addListener('click', function () {
        //  console.log(marcador['geo']);
        mostrarInfoMarcas(marcador['user'], marcador['geo']);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution,
I create the marker by OverlayView Object
So You can treat it as DIV and input the HTML content

```js
function CustomMarker(latlng, map, args) {
 this.latlng = latlng; 
 this.args = args; 
 this.setMap(map); 
}
CustomMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
CustomMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
 
 var self = this;
 var div = this.div;
 if (!div) {
  div = this.div = document.createElement('div');
  var style = '';
  var content = '';
  if (typeof(self.args.marker_style) !== 'undefined') {
   style = self.args.marker_style;
   div.className = 'iot-node-'+style; 
   
  }
  

  if (typeof(self.args.marker_content) !== 'undefined') {
   content = self.args.marker_content;
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   var cur = this.getPosition();
   a.style.backgroundColor='blue';
   a.style.color = 'white';
   a.style.fontSize = "3em";
   a.style.textAlign= "center";
   a.innerHTML = (content=="-1"?"-":content);
   var sub_div = document.createElement('div');
   
   sub_div.style.paddingLeft = '2px';
   var sub_info = self.args.marker_info; 
   sinfo = '<BR>'+sub_info.name+'<BR>'+
     '<font size=2>'+sub_info.office+'</font>';
     
   sub_div.innerHTML = sinfo;
   sub_div.className = 'showme';
   sub_div.style.lineHeight=  "16px";
   sub_div.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
   sub_div.style.color = 'white';
   a.appendChild(sub_div);

   div.appendChild(a);
   
   
   
   if(style=='info') {
    var span =  document.createElement('span');
   
    span.innerHTML = 'x';
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(span, "click", function(event) {
     
    });
    
    //a.appendChild(span);
   }
   
  }
  if (typeof(self.args.marker_style) !== 'undefined' && style!='') {
    var cur = this.getPosition();
    var me  = this;
    
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
    var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.getPosition());
    if (point) {
     if(style!='info') {
      div.style.left = (point.x-20 ) + 'px';
      div.style.top  = (point.y-10)  + 'px';
      var my_info= null;

      
      var sub = {latLng: cur, style: 'info',  content: root_content.replace('[type]', style.toUpperCase()).replace('[address]', addr)};
      my_info= create_node(map, sub);  
      nd.push(my_info);
      

     
     } else {
      
      div.style.left = (point.x - 35 ) + 'px';
      div.style.top  = (point.y - 60 )  + 'px';
      
     }
    }
  }
  
 }
};
CustomMarker.prototype.remove = function() {
 
 if (this.div) {
  this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
  this.div = null;
 } 
 this.setMap(null);
 
};
CustomMarker.prototype.getPosition = function() {
 return this.latlng; 
};

function create_node(map, node) {
 return new CustomMarker(
  node.latLng, 
  map,
  {
   marker_style: node.style,
   marker_content: node.content,
   marker_info: node.info
  }
 );
}






var map;

function initialize() {
   var centerLat = 21.04731;     //default lat
   var centerLng = 105.792137;    //default long
   var cen = new google.maps.LatLng(centerLat, centerLng) ;
   
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: cen,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }); 
    Draw();
}

var nd  = [];
function Draw() {
  
  var lastest_json='{"markers":[{"markerId":"1","name":"Marker1","info":"INFO1","lat":"21.04731","lon":"105.792137"}]}'
  var json_dev =  JSON.parse(lastest_json);
  var markers     = json_dev.markers;
  
  for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++)
  {
   var dev = markers[i];
   var cen = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(dev.lat), parseFloat(dev.lon));
  
   var sub = {latLng: cen, style: 'info', info: dev, content: dev.markerId};
   nd.push(create_node(map, sub)); 
  }
    
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',initialize);
```

```css
 .iot-node-ae, .iot-node-asn, .iot-node-adn, .iot-node-mn, .iot-node-in, .iot-node-info {
 position: absolute;
 list-style-type: none;
 left: 20px;
 top: 20px;
}

.iot-node-ae>a, .iot-node-asn>a, .iot-node-adn>a, .iot-node-mn>a, .iot-node-in>a, .iot-node-info>a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
 border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
 border-color: #0079ff;
 border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
 text-align:left;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-top:0px;
 padding-left:0px;
 padding-right:0px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}


.iot-node-info>a {
   width: 60px;
   height: 35px;
   position: relative;
   border-radius: 0;
}
.iot-node-info>a>span {
position: absolute; top: 2px; right:2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.iot-node-info>a>span::hover {
position: absolute; top: 2px; right:2px;
cursor: pointer;
  
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
}

.iot-node-info>a::before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
   left: 0;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-left: 13px solid transparent;
   border-right: 26px solid #0079ff;
   border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
   
}


.iot-node-info>a>div {
 display:none;
}

.iot-node-info>a:hover > .showme{
 width: 150px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:-70px;
    left:-45px;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:#0079ff;
 display:block;
}

.iot-node-ae::after, .iot-node-asn::after , .iot-node-adn::after , .iot-node-mn::after , .iot-node-in::after , .iot-node-info::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 //animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;

}

 
@keyframes cd-pulse
{
 0%  {box-shadow:0 0 0 0 #0079ff}
 100%{box-shadow:0 0 0 20px rgba(255,150,44,0)}
}
/* AE */
.iot-node-ae{
 
}
.iot-node-ae>a{
  background: #ff3300;
  font-size:14px;
}

.iot-node-ae::after{
 //animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
}

/* asn */
.iot-node-asn{
 
}
.iot-node-asn>a{
  background:  #cc9900;
}

.iot-node-asn::after{
 //animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
}

/* adn */
.iot-node-adn{
 
}
.iot-node-adn>a{
  background:  #330099;
}

.iot-node-adn::after{
 //animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
}

/* mn */
.iot-node-mn{
 
}
.iot-node-mn>a{
  background: #669900;
}

.iot-node-mn::after{
 //animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
}

/* IN */
.iot-node-in{
 
}
.iot-node-in>a{
  background: #ff9900;
  font-size:14px;
}


.iot-node-in::after{
 //animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 238px; "></div>
```